# How to repeatedly call methods in initState without reloading the page?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a page with `initState method`. When I open the page, I run requests in the `initState method`. In requests, I use the `CodeEmailVerif.code global variable`. Tell me, if I change the value of a variable, how can I tell it and call methods in `initState` again without reloading the page?

**main**

```
@override
  void initState() {
    final appState = Provider.of<AppState>(context, listen: false);
    final ProfileCubit cubit = BlocProvider.of<ProfileCubit>(context);
    final CurrentEmailCubit currentEmailCubit =
        BlocProvider.of<CurrentEmailCubit>(context);

      if (CodeEmailVerif.code != null) {
        SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
          final CurrentEmailCubit currentEmailCubit =
              BlocProvider.of<CurrentEmailCubit>(context);
          await currentEmailCubit.getCurrentEmail();
          currentEmailCubit
              .confirmEmail(
                  code: widget.code ?? '',
                  email: currentEmailCubit.currentEmail)
              .then((value) {
            if (value) {
              cubit.fetchProfile(context).then((value) {
                final profileState = cubit.state;
                if (profileState is ProfileLoaded) {
                  appState.isEmailVerif = profileState.user!.isEmailConfirmed;
                  if (appState.isEmailVerif) {
                    _emailSuccessVerifDialog();
                  }
                }
              });
            }
          });
        });
      } else {
        SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
          await currentEmailCubit.getCurrentEmail();
          await cubit.fetchProfile(context).then((value) {
            final profileState = cubit.state;
            if (profileState is ProfileLoaded) {
              appState.isEmailVerif = profileState.user!.isEmailConfirmed;
              if (!appState.isEmailVerif) {
                _emailDialog();
              } 
            }
          });
        });
      }
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
```

**global_variable**

```
class CodeEmailVerif {
  static String? code;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think skip 1st three line, but if you need, you can wrap everything inside listener, I am going to use `ValueNotifier` with modifying the class. Also, I don't think you can skip using static variable for this case.

```dart
class CodeEmailVerif {
  String? _code;
  String? get code => _code;

  CodeEmailVerif({String? value}) {
    _code = value;
  }
}

final ValueNotifier<CodeEmailVerif?> myNotifier = ValueNotifier(
  CodeEmailVerif(),
);
```

To update value use

```dart
 myNotifier.value = CodeEmailVerif(value: count.toString());
```

```dart
 @override
  void initState() {
    myNotifier.addListener(() {
      final appState = Provider.of<AppState>(context, listen: false);
      final ProfileCubit cubit = BlocProvider.of<ProfileCubit>(context);
      final CurrentEmailCubit currentEmailCubit =
          BlocProvider.of<CurrentEmailCubit>(context);
      //* you can put theses above listner
      if (myNotifier.value?.code != null) {
        SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
          final CurrentEmailCubit currentEmailCubit =
              BlocProvider.of<CurrentEmailCubit>(context);
          await currentEmailCubit.getCurrentEmail();
          currentEmailCubit
              .confirmEmail(
                  code: widget.code ?? '',
                  email: currentEmailCubit.currentEmail)
              .then((value) {
            if (value) {
              cubit.fetchProfile(context).then((value) {
                final profileState = cubit.state;
                if (profileState is ProfileLoaded) {
                  appState.isEmailVerif = profileState.user!.isEmailConfirmed;
                  if (appState.isEmailVerif) {
                    _emailSuccessVerifDialog();
                  }
                }
              });
            }
          });
        });
      } else {
        SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
          await currentEmailCubit.getCurrentEmail();
          await cubit.fetchProfile(context).then((value) {
            final profileState = cubit.state;
            if (profileState is ProfileLoaded) {
              appState.isEmailVerif = profileState.user!.isEmailConfirmed;
              if (!appState.isEmailVerif) {
                _emailDialog();
              }
            }
          });
        });
      }
      super.initState();
    });
  }
```

Comment: Is this the way to call initState again even if I don't reload the page?

Comment: And tell me, if I need to update the value of a variable on another screen, then I just need to write myNotifier.value = ... or how will the application understand which variable I'm referring to?

Comment: Yes It will understand changes by  `myNotifier.value=CodeEmailVerif(value: YourStringValue); `

Comment: You can  provide different key to the widget, which will rebuild the full widget from 1st

Comment: According to your example, changes will be tracked and a request will be called in initState when the change occurs?

Comment: Yes, inner methods will get call based on `myNotifier`'s value, when ever it get changed , it will notify the inner methods

Comment: And the page itself will not reload?

Comment: No page will not reload until you do something to update the UI, I mean calling setState or updating UI with stateManagement .

Comment: That is, the page will not reload, the user will not see the changes, but the methods will be called when the variable changes, as I understand it

Comment: Okay, I'm late now, I'll try your code tomorrow morning and give you an answer.

Comment: I checked, initState is not called again, if the variable has changed and the page remains open, it does not reload

Comment: You like to all the methods that are inside initState am i right? the wrapper will do the job, also you can include `super.initState();` inside as well

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake, I forgot to add addListener, everything works now, thanks a lot for your help!)

Comment: Tell me, do I need to close addListener in the dispose method? If yes, could you show how?

Answer (score 0):

Just put the code that is in initState in a method you create, call this method from initState and from anywhere else you need.

Comment: How can I call these methods from initState without doing anything?

Comment: I need the method itself to be called if the value of the variable has changed